# Whether SQL SSIS step by step workflow will be better as compared to SQL jobs step by step workflow?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

We have been using SQL Jobs for calling so many workflow activities.All the steps are mentioned step by step process in the SQL Jobs. We are wondering whether moving these step by step process from SQL Jobs to SQL SSIS will improve the performance as well as more robust with minimal errors.

One of the common problem we face with SQL jobs, If any of our stored procedure either failed to Insert Records due  to some Bad Data .. It fails the SQL jobs. If the SQL job fails, it takes us some time to debug and understand why it is failed.

It will be great to hear comments from SQL Experts.

Comment: What  you mean with 'step by step' is unclear. The SQL Server Agent job should have only one step, if the transactions are dependent on each other. You may want to read and understand about 'transactions' in SQL Server. Using transactions you can control the integrity of the whole process. If you can acomplish your task in a simple job, there is no justification for SSIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep the steps in the job.   That way if one of the steps fails, you can easily see which step it was in the job history.  Also you can easily restart the job starting with the step that failed.

If you only have one step that calls an SSIS package, you will have to carefully write some custom error reporting in the package, or you won't know which step in the package caused the package to fail.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense. This is what we are following now. But if Bad Data  fail to insert, it fails the job !!

Comment: Of course it does.   What else would you want it to do?   If you want it to continue with the other steps, you can set that behavior in the job.

Comment: i think .. we might move the bad data to a BadDataTable ..!! and keep run the good data. Records in the BadData, we can analyze and fix it.

Comment: Other problem is , our SQL Jobs execute some .exe files .. ( Console Applications ) .. Sometimes .exe might be running forever. We manually go to the Server and kill the .exe and rerun the job from that step. We need to address this issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using SSIS for 6 years now building our Enterprise Data Warehouse Star schema. Our sources include AS400 that provide the data in .TSV files (tab delimited).

I wouldn't dream of having to do all the work of an ETL tool just by stored procedures.

With the sue of SSIS i am having 3 databases build up:

-ODS
-Staging
-Final DW.

From all the steps included there are some that you could do with stored procedures.

By using SSIS or another competent ETL tool, you gain in areas such as:

-Bulk data insert
-FAST cleansing of data
-Logging
-Continuation of process in case of errors and general very good error handling.
-Ways to cope with special aspects such as Slow changing dimensions.
-Run / test configuration
-Distributed execution

Remember each tool has its strengths and weaknesses. ETL tools are ,made for doing what you do with general purpose SQL development.

Moreover if you make the transition to using SSIS you will discover business areas that are poorly addressed in your current situation.

I believe that you should invest some of your time on Kimball's site and books.

Specifically take a look at this question in his site: [Should you use an ETL tool?](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/04/should-you-use-an-etl-tool/)

Comment: Okay great thanks !! I agree with you about SSIS is made for ETL Tools. So you say for any ETL Operation .. Calling Stored Procedure in SSIS Would be the right option ???

Comment: Generally rule of thumb in Data Warehousing is to let ETL do most of the job and minimize the jobs  for stored procedure..You should really take a look at Ralph Kimball's books and his site. Take alink for the question "Should you use an ETL tool?" http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/04/should-you-use-an-etl-tool/

Comment: @e4rthdog this may be true in some EDW environments, but I would not recommend it in an MPP one - let the MPP database handle the heavy set-based processing. As always in an EDW, YMMV.

Comment: I believe that he means "massively parallel processing" but that has  to do with appliances and a whole different game. Even then ETL with SSIS can be highly parallelized in all steps..